# How to determine the min/max version of GCC for a given compilation flag?

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-options

I added a compilation flag I found in [GCC Options Summary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html), only to discover that GCC 7 didn't know about that one (we use Continuous Integration systems where many versions are started one after the other, and each failure means the whole build fails and we don't get to build the next version).

The site doesn't include a version range for each option so, apart from testing every single compiler version one by one, is there a simpler way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this. Using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1cc55o74T):

- Use the following program: `int main() {}`
- Above the source code you can click `Add new...` > `Conformance Viewer` and make a list of all the compilers you support and set the flag for each one.

Answer (score 1):

Create a small valid test program and test if it compiles with the test flag. If it compiles, means the flag is supported.

Build systems exist to simplify such work, like CMake `check_c_compiler_flag` or autotools `ax_check_compile_flag`.

Comment: These methods tell me if it works for the single gcc/g++ version used during build. I'm looking for either concrete documentation, or a way to check multiple versions at once.

Comment: what for? It's not like you use many gcc versions during build. Why do you need to know if the flag is supported by gcc version 1.0.0, if you don't use it? You stated: `we use Continuous Integration systems where many versions are started one after the other` - for each version, check if the flag is supported, and use it or not. This is how the problem is solved.

Comment: I do not think it's in the documentation, you can either traverse git tree and grep each tagged version for the option, or traverse each html documentation if the option is documented or not. The only way of not traversing, is to check release notes, but sometimes the option is not mentioned there. Either way, you end up checking each version if it supports or not. Checking the compilation with that flag, is a generalization, that also handles some edge cases. You can also do poor mans solution and do `strings /usr/bin/gcc | grep -- --flag`

Comment: Oh so you mean the flag is conditionally tested THEN used if it worked, right? Often the flags are written in the CMakeLists using generator expressions, which needs the right version. Guess we did it wrong the whole time then.

Comment: `right?` Well, yea. Like so: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/CMake/vtkCompilerExtraFlags.cmake#L10 . It's usually a pattern `check_cxx_copmiler_flag(flag VAR) if (VAR) add_compile_options(flag)`. `Often the flags are written in the CMakeLists using generator expressions` Mostly do not use generator expressions, unless you are dealing with multi-config build generators.